# Binary number with two one insite it

Tags: algorithm, binary, pseudocode

is there an algorithm that find all binaries numbers between a and b, in which there are exactly two one?
For example:

```
a = 5
b = 10
find(a, b)
```

It will find

```
5 = 00000101
6 = 00000110
9 = 00001001
10 = 00001010
```

Comment: Do you have a preferred language like C or Javascript?

Comment: C or Java, but pseudocode is also good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit-hacking trick that iterates through all bit-paterns that contain the same number of 1-bits looks as follows

```
unsigned next_combination(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned u = x & -x;
  unsigned v = u + x;
  x = v + (((v ^ x) / u) >> 2);
  return x;
}
```

It generates the values in ascending order. It takes the previous value and transforms it into the next one with the same number of 1-bits. This means that you just have to start from the minimal bit combination that is greater or equal to `a` and iterate until you encounter a value greater than `b`.

Of course, in this form it will only work if your `a` and `b` are within the range of `unsigned`.

Comment: `-` has no effect on unsigned.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the values are iterated in increasing order ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust: This code is in C or C++. And yes, in C and in C++ unary `-` works (has effect) on `unsigned`.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Yes, it is guaranteed that the numbers are generated in increasing order (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-higher-number-with-same-number-of-set-bits/)

Comment: @AnT Thanks also for the reference

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are of the form

```
2^m + 2^n
```

with `m > n`.

You can find them by exhaustive search on `m`, `n`.

```
M= 1
while M < b:
    N= 1
    while M + N <= b:
        if a <= M + N:
            print M + N
        N+= N
    M+= M
```

This can probably slightly be optimized to avoid searching when `2^m < a`, but the benefit will be tiny: the complexity is `O(log²b)`, which is already small.